# Writing to multiple adjacent columns in pandas efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

With a numpy ndarray it is possible to write to multiple columns at a time without making a copy first (as long as they are adjacent). If I wanted to write to the first three columns of an array I would write

```
a[0,0:3] = 1,2,3 # this is very fast ('a' is a numpy ndarray)
```

I was hoping that in pandas I would similarly be able to select multiple adjacent columns by "label-slicing" like so (assuming the first 3 columns are labeled 'a','b','c')

```
a.loc[0,'a':'c'] = 1,2,3 # this works but is very slow ('a' is a pandas DataFrame)
```

or similarly

```
a.iloc[0,3:6] = 1,2,3 # this is equally as slow
```

However, this takes several 100s of milliseconds as compared to writing to a numpy array which takes only a few microseconds. I'm unclear on whether pandas is making a copy of the array under the hood. The only way I could find to write to the dataframe in this way that gives good speed is to work on the underlying ndarray directly

```
a.values[0,0:3] = 1,2,3 # this works fine and is fast
```

Have I missed something in the Pandas docs or is their no way to do multiple adjacent column indexing on a Pandas dataframe with speed comparable to numpy?

**Edit**

Here's the actual dataframe I am working with.

```
>> conn = sqlite3.connect('prath.sqlite')
>> prath = pd.read_sql("select image_id,pixel_index,skin,r,g,b from pixels",conn)
>> prath.shape
(5913307, 6)
>> prath.head()
   image_id  pixel_index  skin    r    g    b
0        21       113764     0    0    0    0
1        13       187789     0  183  149  173
2        17       535758     0  147   32   35
3        31         6255     0  116    1   16
4        15       119272     0  238  229  224
>> prath.dtypes
image_id       int64
pixel_index    int64
skin           int64
r              int64
g              int64
b              int64
dtype: object
```

Here is some runtime comparisons for the different indexing methods (again, pandas indexing is **very** slow)

```
>> %timeit prath.loc[0,'r':'b'] = 4,5,6
1 loops, best of 3: 888 ms per loop
>> %timeit prath.iloc[0,3:6] = 4,5,6
1 loops, best of 3: 894 ms per loop
>> %timeit prath.values[0,3:6] = 4,5,6
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about `a.loc[0,'a':'c'] = 1,2,3` works for me

Comment: It is not making a copy in the sense that the code is definitely changing the array itself: but it is certainly much much slower than accessing values directly: in the order of 133uS (a.loc[0,'a':'c']) versus 8uS (a.values[0,0:3]) - that's a really good question, why that is so.

Comment: Dataframes don't necessarily behave in a parallel way to numpy arrays.  It can depend on the heterogeneity of datatypes among other things.  In this case, it may help to explain behavior if you can show how you are constructing both the array and dataframe.

Comment: @JohnE I've updated my question to show the dataframe that I'm working on. The numpy array is just the underlying `values` attribute of the dataframe.

Comment: @RobertMuil Isn't it possible that a copy is happening under the hood? Your point about accessing multiple columns in this way (without writing) is also valid - it is ~10x slower in pandas than in numpy. But I think it is a slightly different question and not as severe as the ~100,000x slowdown when *writing* to multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit to clarify:**  I don't believe pandas has a direct analog to setting a view in numpy in terms of both speed and syntax.  `iloc` and `loc` are probably the most direct analog in terms of syntax and purpose, but are much slower.  This is a fairly common situation with numpy and pandas.  Pandas does a lot more than numpy (labeled columns/indexes, automatic alignment, etc.), but is slower to varying degrees.  When you need speed and can do things in numpy, then do them in numpy.

---

I think in a nutshell that the tradeoff here is that `loc` and `iloc` will be slower but work 100% of the time whereas `values` will be fast but not always work (to be honest, I didn't even realize it would work in the way you got it to work).

But here's a really simple example where `values` doesn't work because column 'g' is a float rather than integer.

```
prath['g'] = 3.33

prath.values[0,3:6] = 4,5,6

prath.head(3)

   image_id  pixel_index  skin    r     g    b
0        21       113764     0    0  3.33    0
1        13       187789     0  183  3.33  173
2        17       535758     0  147  3.33   35

prath.iloc[0,3:6] = 4,5,6

prath.head(3)

   image_id  pixel_index  skin    r     g    b
0        21       113764     0    4  5.00    6
1        13       187789     0  183  3.33  173
2        17       535758     0  147  3.33   35
```

You can often get numpy-like speed and behavior from pandas when columns are of homogeneous type, you want to be careful about this.  **Edit to add:** As @toes notes in the comment, the documentation does state that you can do this with homogeneous data.  However, it's potentially very error prone as the example above shows, and I don't think many people would consider this a good general practice in pandas.

My general recommendation would be to do things in numpy in cases where you need the speed (and have homogeneous data types), and pandas when you don't.  The nice thing is that numpy and pandas play well together so it's really not that hard to convert between dataframes and arrays as you go.

**Edit to add:**  The following seems to work (albeit with a warning) even with column 'g' as a float.  The speed is in between the `values` way and `loc/iloc` ways.  I'm not sure if this can be expected to work all the time though.  Just putting it out as a possible middle way.

```
prath[0:1][['r','g','b']] = 4,5,6
```

Comment: thanks for the insight. Your response prompted me to search the pandas documentation where I learned that modifying the underlying `values` ndarray in-place is *only* supported when the data is homogeneous (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#attributes-and-the-raw-ndarray-s). Writing to the dataframe in the way you mention in your edit misses the point of my question though because it is guaranteed to make a copy of the data.

Comment: @toes "Misses the point" is a little harsh!  ;-)  I guess if you want me to explicitly state it, I don't believe it is possible to do what you want without making a copy.  Btw you might mean *set* rather than *select* in your question title?  Anyway, you're trying to apply a numpy concept to pandas and it doesn't work like that.  My edit was merely an attempt to find something faster.  I'll edit the answer to make this more obvious.

Comment: @toes I'm also a little confused about your question in the following sense.  You seem to be asking both how to set without copy and how to do this faster as if it's the same question.  But they are separate (though related of course) questions.  FWIW, I attempted to answer it more from a speed (and safety) perspective rather than focusing on the technicality of copy/view.

Comment: That *was* a little harsh, sorry about that :). It's a result of my question being unclear as you stated. I assumed that pandas must be making a copy under the hood for it to be that slow and that if I could get around the copy it would be just as fast as numpy so that's why I lumped the 'fast' and 'non-copying' together. Maybe a better way to say it is I want this type of assignment to work as fast or nearly as fast as numpy. I'll rework my question a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: @toes  LOL, no worries.  I'll edit to clarify in any event.

Answer (score 2):

We are adding the ability to index directly even in a multi-dtype frame. This is in master now and will be in 0.17.0. You can do this in < 0.17.0, but it requires (more) manipulation of the internals.

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame({'A' : range(5), 'B' : range(6,11), 'C' : 'foo'})

In [2]: df.dtypes
Out[2]: 
A     int64
B     int64
C    object
dtype: object
```

The `copy=False` flag is new. This gives you a dict of dtypes->blocks (which are dtype separable)

```
In [3]: b = df.as_blocks(copy=False)

In [4]: b
Out[4]: 
{'int64':    A   B
 0  0   6
 1  1   7
 2  2   8
 3  3   9
 4  4  10, 'object':      C
 0  foo
 1  foo
 2  foo
 3  foo
 4  foo}
```

Here is the underlying numpy array.

```
In [5]: b['int64'].values
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0,  6],
       [ 1,  7],
       [ 2,  8],
       [ 3,  9],
       [ 4, 10]])
```

This is the array in the original data set

```
In [7]: id(df._data.blocks[0].values)
Out[7]: 4429267232
```

Here is our view on it. They are the same

```
In [8]: id(b['int64'].values.base)
Out[8]: 4429267232
```

Now you can access the frame, and use pandas set operations to modify.
You can also directly access the numpy array via `.values`, which is now a VIEW into the original.

You will not incur any speed penalty for modifications as copies won't be made as long as you don't change the dtype of the data itself (e.g. don't try to put a string here; it will work but the view will be lost)

```
In [9]: b['int64'].loc[0,'A'] = -1

In [11]: b['int64'].values[0,1] = -2
```

Since we have a view, you can then change the underlying data.

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   A   B    C
0 -1  -2  foo
1  1   7  foo
2  2   8  foo
3  3   9  foo
4  4  10  foo
```

Note that if you modify the shape of the data (e.g. if you add a column for example) then the views will be lost.

Comment: Hef Jeff, this looks great.  But to be clear, all the code you are showing here (in terms of setting values) won't work until version 0.17, right?

Comment: How about indexing multiple columns directly as in `df.loc[0,'A':'B']`? Will I be able to do this or would I have to use `as_blocks` to get a view first?

Comment: no, if you really really care about setting values individuall a LOT (and IMHO no good reason to do it this way), then you will have to use the procedure as outlined above.. You are much better off constructing an ndarray (or Series) as you need it then just setting it all at once.