# Is it possible to convert a numpy array of strings to a pandas dataframe inplace?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

As you can see, the array has been copied.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
foo = np.array([['a', 'b'],['c', 'd']],dtype='U32')
df_foo = pd.DataFrame(data=foo, copy=False)
foo[0,0]='different'
print(df_foo.values)
```

Returns

```
[['a' 'b']
 ['c' 'd']]
```

Furthermore, `foo` has `dtype='<U32'` while `df_foo.values` has `dtype=object`.  I don't need a solution to the problem, I'm more curious as to whether it's possible and if not, why not?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, although Jeff has discussed an upcoming feature in 0.17.0 that I believe would be pretty similar to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132784/writing-to-multiple-adjacent-columns-in-pandas-efficiently/31167101#31167101

Comment: this is not possible even with no copies - strings are represented as object dtype so they are copied on conversion. if u started as object dtype it would be view (iow what you are trying would work). But their are many odd issues with object types so no guarantees when you do operations and you may lose the view in lots of cases.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just remove copy=False and then it won't be a copy. So just replace

```
df_foo = pd.DataFrame(data=foo, copy=False)
```

with

```
df_foo = pd.DataFrame(data=foo)
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure?  I'm sorry, but this does not make sense to me.  Try to run my code with what you're saying and see if you get `different' printed out in the first cell.  Also I think this question was answered by @Jeff in the comments to the question.  I would mark his reply as an answer if it was posted as an answer.